# Take full screenshot in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, screenshot

I developed a little chrome extension, which takes a screenshot from the current page. The Problem is, when a part of the current area is covered by e.g. the inspector or not in view the screenshot gets cropped.
Is there a way to get the full screen?
Here my Code (stripped down):

```
function createScreenshot() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png" }, function (screenshotUrl) {
        cropImage(screenshotUrl, "Screenshot");
      });
  });
}

function cropImage(url, fileName) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
      downloadImage(canvas, fileName + ".png");
    });
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

for example, this is the page i want to shot in a 4k res:

- [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS49D.png)

as you can see, it doesn't fit to the actual screen resolution but the result is only the active area (even smaller):

- [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JuMT.png)

is there a way to get the "not visible" part?

Regrads,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

There is minor correction in your code

you have to pass canvas width, height in drawImage

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

You will need to get the base64 string

```
let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Finally, you will get the result you want

Hope this solution will help you

Comment: Hi there, I tried your code, but in the end, I still get only the visible part of the screen, not the full resolution I set via DevTools. Debug output of canvas.w and .h are the visible area, so it seems the captureVisibleTab-method doesn't render things, that aren't visible...

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested here [in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/11cluac/building_a_chrome_extension_any_way_to_take_a/)

```
 chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: "png"}, function(dataUrl) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataUrl;
  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"}, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: "png"}, function(dataUrl) {
          var img2 = new Image();
          img2.src = dataUrl;
          img2.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, img.height, img2.width, img2.height);
            var finalDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            // Use finalDataUrl as needed
          }
        });
      }, 500);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).